# create visual web part in sharepoint connect to a list

Tags: sharepoint-2010, web-parts, sharepoint-list

I want to create a visual web part in share point 2010 can read and write data form a share point list. how can I do it?
I programing with vs2010 on a share point server.

Answer (score 0):

Search online for SharePoint 2010 HOL (Hands-on-Lab).  It will probably be on msdn.com for download.

Those tutorials will walk you through step-by-step basic Visual Studio SharePoint development.

Answer (score 0):

You can find several examples on the internet.  Try these examples -

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff597539(v=office.14).aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/136857/Developing-Web-Parts-for-Sharepoint-2010